# Producing Exponential Generating Functions For Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, exponential-function, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Exponential generating functions, becomes very complex and i just got the hang of non exponential function. And i am trying to apply the same methods that i used for regular generating functions. for example: the number of way to make n dollars among 5 people would be $(\frac{1}{1-x})^5$ . Now for exponential generating function for the number of words of length $n$ using letters $a, b, c, d, e$ such that all five letters occur with no restrictions

Im wondering if anyone can assist with starting out the generating function for letter with word length $n$ would it be the generating function of $e^{5x}$

And then for 10 letters ill expand and look for the $\frac{x^{10}}{10!}$ coefficient

the following question after no restrictions is that at least three of the letters appear?

$(e^x-1)^3e^{2x}$ .. is  this generating function correct for at least three letters appear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed answer, $(e^x-1)^3e^{2x}$, is the exponential generating function for the problem of counting the number of words composed of the letters *a, b, c, d, e* in which *a, b,* and *c* each appear at least once.  But I believe your problem is different: at least three different letters must appear, but they can be any three of the letters.

One way to approach the problem is to break it down into three cases:

1. exactly three different letters appear,
2. exactly four different letters appear,
3. exactly five different letters appear.

The generating functions for the three cases are $10(e^x-1)^3$, $5(e^x-1)^4$, and $(e^x-1)^5$.  The coefficients are the numbers of ways of determining the set of letters that appear: $10=\binom{5}{3}$, $5=\binom{5}{4}$, $1=\binom{5}{5}$.

Summing these gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
(e^x-1)^3((e^x-1)^2+5(e^x-1)+10)&=(e^x-1)^3(e^{2x}+3e^x+6)\\
&=e^{5x}-10e^{2x}+15e^x-6.
\end{aligned}
$$
This last expression can be understood using the principle of inclusion-exclusion: $e^{5x}$ is the exponential generating function for words composed of the letters *a, b, c, d, e.*  We must exclude words that use two or fewer of the five letters.  We define $S_{a,b}$ to be the set of words composed of *a* and *b*, and similarly for other letter pairs.  The exponential generating function for $S_{a,b}$ is $e^{2x}$; that there are $10$ letter pairs accounts for the $-10e^{2x}$ term.  Words composed of only a single letter have been subtracted too many times, and must be added back.  Words composed only of the letter *a*, for example, have been subtracted four times, so we add them back three times, and similarly for the other four letters.  This accounts for the $+15e^x$ term.  Finally, the empty word has been added once, subtracted $10$ times, and added back $15$ times. Since the empty word does not use three letters, we need the $-6$ term to produce the correct count of $0$ for the empty word.

One can also achieve this result by doing a detailed analysis of the exponential generating functions for the intersections $S_{w,x}\cap S_{y,z}$, and similarly for three-, four-, etc. up to 10-set intersections.  Of the $\binom{10}{2}=45$ two-set intersections, for example, $30$ have exponential generating function $e^x$ ($S_{a,b}\cap S_{a,c}$, for example), while $15$ have exponential generating function $1$ ($S_{a,b}\cap S_{c,d}$, for example).  Similarly, $20$ of the three-set intersections have exponential generating function $e^x$ and $100$ have exponential generating function $1$, five of the four-set intersections have exponential generating function $e^x$ and $205$ have exponential generating function $1$, and all of the five- and higher set intersections have exponential generating function $1$.  After all additions and subtractions have been performed, we obtain the result above.